# Beautifulsoup extract comment section

Tags: python

I wanted to extract an item inside a comment block like this one

`<!-- stuff = 'value'; ...`

the item be extracted is 'value'.

any suggestions on how I can achive that with regex in python?

Comment: How about using regular expressions?

Comment: It still does'nt answer my question please see it through

Comment: you need the common pattern for `stuff =value` in all the occurrences to extract using regular expression. I do not know what beautiful soap module does. And unaware of any module which would be designed for your purpose